# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on integer

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo, while-loop

I'm working on a website; apache asks me to upgrade to the new method of PDO.

I have my function which will collect all the information of user X, indicated by the variable $_SESSION['username'].

My problem is: I get the error title. However I want to collect String and INT values.

My Function: functions.php

```
function getDetails($username) {
    $db = require("dbConn.php");
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `es42_members` WHERE HandleName='$username'");
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetchAll();

    return $row;
}
```

My index file: index.php

```
$details = getDetails($_SESSION['username']);

while ($row = $details->fetch_assoc())  {
    $id = $row['UserID'];
    $email = $row['Email']; // This return String
    $isAdmin = $row['isAdmin']; //This return 0 - 1. But in the table is registered by String (Varchar).
}

echo "Your email is: $email";
if($isAdmin == "1"){ echo "You are a admin!" }
```

**UPDATE**
My new code is as follows:

Function: @Marcus

```
function getDetails($username) {
    require("dbConn.php");
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `es42_members` WHERE HandleName='$username'");
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetchAll();

    return $row;
}
```

dbConn.php [Original]

```
<?php 

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ProfileTest', "root", "1234");
$db = null;

?>
```

dbConn.php [**Edited and working**]

```
<?php 

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ProfileTest', "root", "1234");

?>
```

Comment: Look at what the error says. `Call to a member function prepare() on integer`. That means `$db` is an integer, not a database connection.

Comment: Also, you typically want to only connect to your database once per request and pass that as a parameter to any function that needs it, or store it as a class property. If you put your connection within your `getDetails` function it won't be available to reuse anywhere else in your script.

Comment: Go through your `dbConn.php` file line-by-line and I think the error is pretty obvious. Come on, you're not even trying here.

Comment: @Mike oh, yes i must remove the  $db = null;. Thanks.

Comment: When you finally get it working, make sure you fix the SQL injection problem you have there. You should be using bound parameters with your prepares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `$db` isn't actually holding the PDO connection object. You've assigned the `dbConn.php` script itself (returns 1 on successful *inclusion*) to `$db`, which is why you're receiving the integer error in question.

Your `dbConn.php` file should look something like the following (please add dbConn.php to your original post for verification):

```
// dbConn.php
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); // PDO has been instantiated and $db is holding the object
```

Then in your `functions.php` script:

```
function getDetails($username) {
    require("dbConn.php"); // require me, don't assign me to a variable
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `es42_members` WHERE HandleName='$username'");
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetchAll();

    return $row;
}
```

You'd simply *require* `dbConn.php` and NOT assign it to any variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since your error message says

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on integer"

i assume the error pops up in your getDetails function where you call `"sql = $db->prepare ..."`

So the error is comming from your $db variable. Post your "dbConn.php" file for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue
I solved it this way and it's working

you just have to add a return statement of `$db` variable.

*Before*

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ProfileTest', "root", "1234");
?>
```

*After*

```
<?php 

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ProfileTest', "root", "1234");
return $db;
?>
```

Then in your getDetails function, you have to initialize the connection as

```
$db = require_once("dbConn.php");
```